# Android Studio: удалить Placeholder

Tags: android, java, intellij-idea

По умолчанию, создается активити с `Placeholder`, это шапка вверху программы с названием и обводкой. как можно ее убрать? код полностью чистил, ничего не помогло

Comment: а код чего вы "чистили?"

Comment: Main activity

Comment: > Placeholder
> шапка вверху программы

Это называется action bar.

Comment: http://instinctcoder.com/remove-default-fragment-in-android-studio-project/ не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Укажите для приложения тему, не содержащую action bar. Например, `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar`. Или плясать от `Theme.AppCompat`, если используете `ActionBar` из support library.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.